# Adding one value and insert it into two tables in asp.net c# using SQL query but in one table it is stored as primary key and autoincrement

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, sql-server, webforms

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MoqRT.png)I have two tables where in table tbl_mngr_shift_handover there mgr_handover_id is primary key and i want to insert it into another table tbl_mngr_shift_handover_details at insert time. So following is asp.net c# code

```
string remarkString = remarkTextArea.Content;
string query = string.Empty;
query="INSERT INTO tbl_mngr_shift_handover(msp_id,cat_id,task_id,priority_id,shift_id,status_id,activity)VALUES('"
     +MSPDropDownList.SelectedValue+"','"
     +CategoryDropDownList.SelectedValue+"','"
     +TaskDropDownList.SelectedValue+"','"
     +PriorityDropDownList.SelectedValue+"','"
     +ShiftDropDownList.SelectedValue+"','"
     +StatusDropDownList.SelectedValue+"','"
     +ActivityTextBox.Text+"')";

string query1 ="INSERT INTO tbl_mngr_shift_handover_details(status_id,remark,inserted_by,inserted_date)"
              +"VALUES('" + StatusDropDownList.SelectedValue + "','"
                          + remarkTextArea.Content + "','"
                          + Session["user_id"] + "','"
                          + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss") + "')";

if(query != null)
{
    string query2 = "update tbl_mngr_shift_handover_details set tbl_mngr_shift_handover_details.mgr_handover_id=tbl_mngr_shift_handover.mgr_handover_id from tbl_mngr_shift_handover where tbl_mngr_shift_handover_details.mgr_handover_id=tbl_mngr_shift_handover.mgr_handover_id ";
    con.ConnectionString = constr;
    con.Open();
    if (con != null)
    {
        cmd1 = new SqlCommand(query2, con);
        cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery();
        con.Close();
    }
}

try
{
    con.ConnectionString = constr;
    con.Open();
    if (con != null)
    {
        cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con);
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        cmd2 = new SqlCommand(query1, con);
        cmd2.ExecuteNonQuery();

        PopUpLabel.Text = "Inserted Successfully";
        ModalPopupExtender2.Show();

    }
}
catch (Exception er)
{
    // Label3.Text += "error in handover : " + er.Message;
    PopUpLabel.Text = "Error While Inserting Handover.Please Concern Your Manager: Error Details: " + er.Message;
    pnlPopup.Visible = true;
    ModalPopupExtender2.Show();

}
finally
{
    con.Close();
}
```

Here is database fields Images
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fpQca.png)

Here In tbl_mngr_shift_handover_details field mgr_handover_id show null vallue so what can i do..

Comment: [SQL Injection alert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161953%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) - you should **not** concatenate together your SQL statements - use **parametrized queries** instead to avoid SQL injection - check out [Little Bobby Tables](https://xkcd.com/327/)

Comment: If the data is already in the table you need to do an update instead of an insert.  A database is a flat object with rows and columns. Tables in a database are views of the database.  Even though you have data may exist in multiple tables they overlap in the database.  ExecuteNonQuery returns an integer indicating the number of rows changed.  If you are doing an insert and you get a zero it indicates the data already exists so you must then do an update to change the existing rows.  If you first do an update and get a zero then you must do an insert because the data is not in the database.

Comment: I suggest you looking up by using select query first to find if the requested data to insert with had already exist. If the data isn't exist then perform insert, otherwise perform update from designated criteria (usually an identity column and/or other set of columns).